# How to prevent Cut/Copy/Paste from Windows Explorer with C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, explorer, windows-forms-core

I am working on an application about preventing cut/copy and paste methods from any user of Windows's like below image.

[sample screenshot](https://www.4dots-software.com/images/disable-context-menu-items/disable-context-menu-items-context-menu-700-375.png)

I've tried `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell` at the registry, but I couldn't make any changes. Is there any way to prevent these items from context menu of Windows Explorer with C#?

Comment: Search about disabling copy and paste from the registry then search about how to edit the registry programmatically by c#: https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/how_to_disable_clipboard_history_in_windows_10.html#:~:text=Open%20the%20Registry%20Editor%20and,to%20enable%20the%20clipboard%20history.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643947/how-can-i-programmatically-change-a-value-in-the-windows-registry

Comment: Thank you for your response but these dont meet my request. Actually I would like to make the buttons disable.

Comment: Why? Users can just drag&drop to move/copy instead. Or use cmd.exe

Comment: I am working for a CX company and some of project managers would like to make customer data safe. CSRs cannot use cmd already. So there is one remains. Disabling copy/cut/paste.

Comment: If your End-users (how they did not allow copying) don't accsec to the registry file, you can use my solution, I have done it before for the same problem.

Comment: Users literally should not see or click cut/copy and paste buttons when right click on anything on Windows

Comment: This seems like a terrible solution to what is basically a security issue. So you disable cut-copy-paste, but a user can still open the document. The associated application still allows the user to cut, copy, and paste the contents of the file. This problem should be solved with appropriate permissions and group policies applied at the folder/share level, not by a hacked-up system-wide solution that disables a feature that is integral to day-to-day operations.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment you can add a registry key to disable the clipboard.

Add a *DWORD* key and named it *AllowClipboardHistory* in
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System"

use a '0' value for avoiding and a '1' value for allowing.

you can use this answer for how to add or delete keys in the registry by C#:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74140796/2286867